# Can't loas csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas, file, csv

I'm new to python and I'm trying to load a csv file using pandas read_csv method.
This is how my code looks like :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/win7/adult_income.csv')
df.head()
```

Here is the error I get :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-38d0404ac873> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/win7/adult_income.csv')
      3 df.head()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    683         )
    684 
--> 685         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    686 
    687     parser_f.__name__ = name

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    455 
    456     # Create the parser.
--> 457     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    458 
    459     if chunksize or iterator:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    893             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    894 
--> 895         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    896 
    897     def close(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1133     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1134         if engine == "c":
-> 1135             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1136         else:
   1137             if engine == "python":

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1915         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1916 
-> 1917         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1918         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1919 

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/win7/adult_income.csv' does not exist: b'C:/Users/win7/adult_income.csv'
```

I don't understand why the file isn't loading and the path of the file is correct. I'm using jupyter notebook to write my code and the path to my code is "C:\Users\win7\Test.ipynb".

Comment: besides checking that the filepath is correct you could try r'C:/Users/win7/adult_income.csv' or 'C://Users//win7//adult_income.csv'

Comment: I tried but it's not working. The path to my file is the correct one.

Comment: @emiljoj Using raw strings is only necessary when you write the path with backslashes.

Comment: thanks, hope backlashes as suggested by Thierry and Sashi work

Comment: I didn't suggest using backslashes, normal slashes '/' are perfectly valid in Windows paths in Python.

Comment: Thank you eveybody. I didn't notice the file was xslx and not csv and this is why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Please confirm that the file is actually in **.csv** format and not in some other format like **.xlsx** or **.ods**. As @Thierry Lathuille suggests, `/` instead of `\` should not be a problem, and is perfectly valid.

Answer (score -1):

Filepath in your error message -> C:/Users/win7/adult_income.csv'
Actual Filepath (probably) -> C:\Users\win7\adult_income.csv'

Notice the difference in 'slash'. / vs \

Comment: Using slashes`/` instead of blackslashes `\\` is perfectly valid for Windows paths in Python.